# How to use certificate from Azure KeyVault with HttpClient without extracting it out of HSM?

Tags: .net, ssl, certificate, httpclient, azure-keyvault

I'm making a call to remote API requiring authentication using SSL certificate with the code like this:

```fs
let httpClient (x509Cert: X509Certificate2) =
    let handler = new HttpClientHandler()
    handler.SslProtocols <- SslProtocols.Tls12
    handler.ClientCertificateOptions <- ClientCertificateOption.Manual
    handler.ClientCertificates.Add(x509Cert) |> ignore
    let client = new HttpClient(handler)
    client
```

The code works fine when using a local certificate (loaded from file or certificate store), but, for security reasons, I'd prefer to use HSM (Azure KeyVault) directly and not to deal with the certificate (or more precisely with the private key part). Is it possible to achieve?

For other purposes whenever a private key is needed (usually an instance of AsymmetricAlgorithm) I use implementation inspired by [RSAKeyVaultProvider library](https://github.com/onovotny/RSAKeyVaultProvider) which delegates signing to HSM instead of fetching the private key from the HSM. I guess this approach could be used here as well, but I cannot find any API that would enable this option. I've dug through the source code of `HttpClient`, `HttpClientHandler` and other related classes but haven't really found anything that could give me some hope.

Has anyone encountered such a challenge? Are there any viable solutions, apart from rewriting whole `HttpClient` stack?

**Update**

From browsing through the .NET source code I've noticed that at some point there is casting of the certificates provided (initially as `X509Certificate`) to `X509Certificate2` and there are checks to validate whether it has a private key and supports required functions (digital signature and client authentication). Given that most of the properties of `X509Certificate2` aren't virtual, I cannot override them in a derived class (one solution I was thinking about). Unless there's something I'm missing out there is very little chance of doing it the way I'd want it to do.

Comment: My initial take when reading this was that you just need to download the entire certificate from Key Vault with both the private and public keys and use it for the client auth.  I describe this process in this blog post:

https://azidentity.azurewebsites.net/post/2018/07/03/azure-key-vault-certificates-are-secrets

On second reading I am unsure if that's what you actually want to do since that would bring the private key to the local machine.  It seems that not having the full certificate would be a problem but I have no idea how to offload the private key part to Key Vault.

Comment: @MattSmall the second reading was more what I am up to. I have a full certificate (public + private key) in KeyVault, but, for security reasons, it's configured to retrieve only public part when fetching it from KV.

I guess I also need to figure out what is the certificate used for in the request, that should get me some insight on the viability of making a request without fetching the private key to the local machine.

Comment: are you using an azure webapp / functions ? if so you can also load your certificate directly to the app from the azure portal

Comment: @Thomas yes, I'm using Functions and I can fetch the certificate using `GetSecret...` methods. The problem is that I wanted to avoid it and use KV directly to generate hash/signature (e.g. `KeyVaultClient.SignAsync` method) as I'm doing now for other tasks requiring private key otherwise.

Comment: I'm checking to see if there's any functionality in the Key Vault that will enable this.